# nginx not loading my project from other server

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have three servers 10.77.12.54,10.77.12.55,10.77.12.56 my application on 54, Postgres on 55, and Nginx on 56 servers I created gunicorn.shock file and gunicorn.server file and I added app IP to Nginx config file and also create sites-available, sites-enabled but Nginx not fetching my application is there anything I have to do?

```
server {
    listen       80;
   server_name  10.77.12.54;
   add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
   add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff always;
   add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
   proxy_cookie_path / "/; Secure";
   access_log  /var/log/nginx/access_rkvy.log main buffer=32k;
    location / {
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/app54log.log main;
        proxy_pass http://loadblncer;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_buffer_size  128k;
        proxy_buffers 100  128k;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the upstream directive of `"http://loadblncer"`?
What is pointing to the web (gunicorn) server?
Also, do you use Nginx for another thing other than gunicorn?

Comment: Does it need Upstream directives because I have only one app server

Comment: What does  `http://loadblncer` represent?